# Customers can't change item quantities on /checkout/cart/

Tags: checkout, cart, magento-community

Does anyone know why my /checkout/cart/ page will not let my customers change the quantity of an item in it please? Is there an easy fix?

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the form key. So your post request is ignores.
Add this line `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` inside the  tag in the template `app/design/frotnend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/cart.phtml`.

Comment: Saved my life mate!!

Answer (score 1):

Means you are not able to update quantity on cart page.
I think the customer has set inventory **Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** if this is then he can not purchase item below it but can purchase more than.
thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried that and https://www.thetelecomshop.com/uk/checkout/cart/  still won't let me edit item qty and update cart.

Comment: Hi as we have checked,I got there is missing ID of input type,without id you can,t update item on cart page. there should be from                                                      <input maxlength="12" class="input-text qty" title="Qty" size="4" value="1" name="cart[11483][qty]">                                                       TO  <input id="something id of product" maxlength="12" class="input-text qty" title="Qty" size="4" value="1" name="cart[11483][qty]">

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, i will pass this to my dev chap :-)